# сделать задержку в цикле for

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть цикл:

```
 if (array.length > 0) {
     for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         $('iframe').contents().find('.ppage:contains("' + array[i] + '")').click();
         //тут нужна задержка
         snapShot(var1, '_p' + array[i]);

     }
 }
```

Там где комент, нужно вставить паузу на некоторое время.
`setInterval`, `setTimeout` не помогают. Подскажите, пожалуйста, другие методы.

Comment: Требуется ли, чтобы цикл завершился только после того, как отработают все итерации, либо итерации можно вынести на асинхронное выполнение?

Comment: чтобы цикл завершился только после того, как отработают все итерации. именно так

Answer (score 4):

Вот вариант решения через `setTimeout` + рекурсию (за такое, конечно, нужно расстреливать):

```
 if (array.length > 0) {
  var foo = function(indx) {
    $('iframe').contents().find('.ppage:contains("' + array[indx] + '")').click();
    window.setTimeout(function() {
            snapShot(var1, '_p' + array[indx]); 
        if(indx < array.length) { 
            foo(indx + 1);      
        } else {
                //действия в конце
        }
    },500);
  }
  foo(0); 
 }
```

Но у вас начнутся проблемы, если длина массива будет меняться во время работы этого скрипта.

Если я правильно понял, то таймаут вам нужен, чтобы убедиться, что во фрейме что-то поменялось. Если так, то более правильным подходом будет вызов во фрейме функции из окна-родителя через каллбэк без всяких таймаутов и рекурсий, а не ожидание "навскидку" что изменения во фрейме уже произошли по истечении таймаута.

Comment: Ваше предложение интересно, попробую

Comment: + в карму. Ваше предложение работает. спасибо

Answer (score 0):

setInterval и setTimeout вам не помогут, так как выполняются в отдельном потоке. Можете конечно сделать какой-нибудь костыль наподобие цикла с пустым телом и огромным количеством итераций. Но если вы хотите чего-то подобного, то скорее всего вы ошибаетесь - подобные трюки обысно свидетельствуют о неправильном выборе средств решения задачи и ни к чему хорошему не приводят

Comment: в том и дело, что протезы не нужны

Comment: ваша задача сама по себе уже выглядит как "протез". Более того, а каким по-вашему должен быть "не протез"? А вообще было бы неплохо, если бы вы более подробно описали задачу и указали, зачем вам понадобились подобные изврращения. Вполне вероятно, что они там вовсе не нужны

Comment: утояняю. Пауза нужна для того, чтоб контент, который вызван через $('iframe').contents().find('.ppage:contains("' + array[i] + '")').click(); успел загрузится.

Comment: ого...вот это уж точно извращение. Вам нужно правильно реализовать   асинхронную модель получения данных. В js практически все завязано на асинхронном обменед анными с сервером

Comment: согласен. без фрейма все классно строится на $.ajaxStart/Stop. С фреймом не катит. код отчасти не мой, вот и ....

Answer (score 0):

Такой функции не существует.
Например вот вариант

```
setTimeout(function() {
  snapShot(var1, '_p' + array[i]);
}, 2000);
```

либо вот

```
function sleep(ms) {
  ms += new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date() < ms){}
}
```

Comment: Я бы не порекомендовал функцию `sleep`, потому что заморозит браузер.

Answer (score -3):

```
if (array.length > 0) {
     for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     $('iframe').contents().find('.ppage:contains("' + array[i] + '")').click();
     setTimeout(function() 
      {
        snapShot(var1, '_p' + array[i]);
      }, 5000);
}
 }
```

Comment: и что же такое sleep в JavaScript?

Comment: не пашет (. или я туплю с синтаксисом.ReferenceError: sleep is not defined
sleep(2000);

Comment: _PHP_ головного мозга...

Comment: Действительно php головного мозга. Утро еще, не проснулся. Исправил.

Comment: такая модель не катит. клики сами по себе, функция по таймауту. должно быть последовательно